# Not able to create custom _Id in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I'm trying to updating data with below code but it's not inserting _id for me,
Also I've used upsert:trure but seems like it's not working too.

```
/* UPDATE LiveFeed socket */    
router.put('/', function(req, res, next) {
    filter=req.params.exchange+req.params.symbol;
    LiveFeed.where({filter}).update({
        _id: filter,
        exchange: req.params.exchange,
        symbol: req.params.symbol,
        timestamp: req.params.timestamp,
        ltp: req.params.ltp,
        close: req.params.close,
        open: req.params.open,
        high: req.params.high,
        low: req.params.low,
        vtt: req.params.vtt,
        atp: req.params.atp,
        oi: req.params.oi,
        spot_price: req.params.spot_price,
        total_buy_qty: req.params.total_buy_qty,
        total_sell_qty: req.params.total_sell_qty,
        lower_circuit: req.params.lower_circuit,
        upper_circuit: req.params.upper_circuit,
        yearly_low: req.params.yearly_low,
        yearly_high: req.params.yearly_high,
        bids: req.params.bids,
        asks: req.params.asks,
        ltt: req.params.ltt
    },
    {
        upsert: true,
        multi: true,
        new: true
    }).exec();
});

//model
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var LiveFeed = new mongoose.Schema({
    _id: String,
    timestamp: String,
    exchange: String,
    symbol: String,
    ltp: Number,
    close: String,
    open: String,
    high: String,
    low: String,
    vtt: Number,
    atp: Number,
    oi: Number,
    spot_price: Number,
    total_buy_qty: String,
    total_sell_qty: String,
    lower_circuit: Number,
    upper_circuit: Number,
    yearly_low:Number,
    yearly_high: Number,
    bids: String,
    asks: String,
    ltt: String,
    updated_date: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    },
},
{
    _id: false
});
module.exports = mongoose.model('LiveFeed', LiveFeed);
```

Answer (score 3):

**Note : You can create custom _id but you can not update _id since it is an Immutable field**

I think you should remove *{_id : false}*
Here is my working code for creating **custom _id**

**Mongoose Model :**

```
var mongoose     = require('mongoose');
var Schema       = mongoose.Schema;

var msgboardSchema = new Schema({
    _id : { type : Number, required : true },
    date: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now,
        },
    msg: String
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('msgboard', msgboardSchema);
```

**To insert data**

```
router.post('/Create', function(req, res) {
    var msg_board = new msgboard();

    msg_board.date = new Date();
    msg_board.msg = req.body.msg;   
    msg_board._id = req.body._id;

    msg_board.save(function(msg_err, msg_test){
        if(msg_err){
            console.log(msg_err);
            res.json(msg_err);
        }else{
            console.log("msgboard data created");
            res.json(msg_test);

        }
    });
});
```

**Output :** [image]

Comment: @user9359064 Is there error while inserting the custom _id value or does_id parameter not exists in db after insertion ?

Comment: @user9359064 So you are trying to update _id (not create) for new value. It is not allowed because it is immutable field. If you add callback to update() then you will see MongoError for trying to update *Immutable field*. You can create custom _id but you cannot update _id because it is immutable field. Refer this https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/tutorial/modify-documents/

Comment: No, I want to do this ::
If _id already present in mongoose just update fields except _id,
If _Id not present then add new record.

Comment: If it is that necessary then you should delete first document with the objectId and insert new document with updated _id. But you can't simply update _id once it is created.